# How to change bool values in c++ using python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I have bunch of C++ scripts which contains bool values for doing or not doing tasks. I need to call those c++ scripts using python-3.X, be able to change the bool values from 0 to 1 for doing something. What is the easiest way to do that? 
For eg: a part of code. And there are various similar tasks that I need to use one at a time from python.

```
bool do_work = 0;
if (do_work)
 task(to_be_done);
```

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: What would the best method or easiest? I tried calling c++ codes from subprocess but I am not sure if I can stick with that or what embedding or extending stuff I should look for? I am really lost.

Comment: I would start here: https://docs.python.org/3.2/extending/  you could also use Boost Python, which might be the easiest: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/index.html   I don't know the exact answer to your question because I've never tried to do what you're trying to do, but those are the first 2 places I would look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful suggestions.